# How can I watch StarCraft 2 games at MLG Dallas?

Tags: starcraft-2

What options are available to me if I don't have time to watch MLG live?

Comment: mlgpro.com  extracharacters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will be hosted later in either their [VoD Section](http://www.mlgpro.com/video/videoOnDemand) or their [VoD Archive](http://www.mlgpro.com/vodarchive).

On the Bridge chat Lee has suggested [this link](http://tv.majorleaguegaming.com/search?page=1&q=Starcraft+2&tag_search=true), but I'm unsure if the Dallas videos will be there...

Comment: It's important to note that most games in the early stages of the tournament aren't broadcast at all. Most - if not all - replays should turn up at the "Match Info" pages linked to in the [winners](http://www.mlgpro.com/ci/brackets/procircuit/10/dallas/sc2/open/winners) and [losers](http://www.mlgpro.com/ci/brackets/procircuit/10/dallas/sc2/open/losers) brackets. These will then in turn be casted by various YouTube commentators.